# kile does not get keyboard input, respond to Alt+F

Tags: gnome, keyboard, kde, kile

I use 11.10 with gnome 3 and Unity. In either case, I use two KDE apps a lot - kile and kate. Since the latest upgrade, I have observed a few problems:

a] I can never use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to select the file menu (works with other apps), yet when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, kile's menu comes up in the status bar.

b] A few times every day, while using kile (haven't used kate as much recently), the keyboard stops responding (just in the 'editor' portion, rather than in structure-tree navigation). I cannot enter any text, but mouse works fine. I usually restart kile to continue working.

One inconsistent way to reproduce it (multiple times today):

- I cut text from one open document using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- switched to another document in the same kile window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then this happened.

c] Sometimes, in kate, I can type in the editor but the keyboard won't work in the `File open dialog`.

How do I fix the above?

Comment: Related [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67904/alt-menu-shortcuts-are-broken-for-kde-apps-under-unity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, not an answer.  Just something to confirm similar issues with Kile.  However, mine is through KDE for Windows.  Some .tex files won't let me edited them in the editor using the keyboard.  Can't copy paste either, but I can move the cursor around and scroll through the .tex file.  I filed a bug on KDE's website here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292766

4-30-12:
Again, not an answer, but now I am experiencing similar problems with the keyboard input after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04.  This is really frustrating as documents (.tex files) that worked fine before no longer allow me to type in them.  I can select and scroll with the mouse but no typing!!!!  Funny thing too is that it only happens for a few documents.

Comment: Aha!  I think I found an answer!!  My solution was simple...of course.  For some reason, the Read Only mode was enabled!!  So simple go to Tools and disable!!  That's it!  Now my issues with Kile and the keyboard input are resolved on both Windows KDE and after I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04!!  Thanks to the responses I got from the KDE community where I posted this "bug" (see link in original post)!!!

Comment: Additional note, apparently Kate and Kile have a restriction on the number of characters per line (1024), and if exceeded, it will open the file read-only.  I did receive this error after the upgrade and of course I ignored it because I did not think it was relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As the Tools and Settings are side by side, sometimes it's possible to enable "Read Only Mode" accidentally instead of selecting something else like "Define Master Document".

Solution :

Go to `Tools` > then check if the `Read Only Mode` is activated. If yes, deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem deleting the `kilerc` file in `.kde/share/config/`. This will reset all your Kile settings, but solves the issue describes in the original post.